# UIlabel with Custom cell not appear

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I'm confused !, it is not my first time to create Custom Cell but this time UILabel doesn't appear I don't know where is the problem ?

This the custom cell Cell.m

```
        mainView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        mainView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:249.0/255.0 green:249.0/255.0 blue:249.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        profile = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        profile.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        profile.layer.cornerRadius = 22.5;
        profile.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
        profile.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
        profile.clipsToBounds = YES;
        tweet_is = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        tweet_is.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:20];
        tweet_is.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        tweet_is.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [self.mainView addSubview:tweet_is];
        [self.mainView addSubview:profile];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.mainView];

-(void)layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.mainView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height - 10.0f);
    self.profile.frame = CGRectMake(15, 15, 45, 45);
    self.tweet_is.frame = CGRectMake(30, 30, 300.0f, 300.0f);

}
```

This is the tableView

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    Cell *cell = (Cell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[Cell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.tweet_is.text = @"Not approve";
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I did a test to change background color of the UILabel, it show the back ground color without TEXT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
self.tweet_is.frame = CGRectMake(30, 30, 300.0f, 300.0f);
```

set it `self.tweet_is.frame = CGRectMake(30, 30, 300.0f, 30.0f);`

If your cell height is less than 300 (I think it is) then you can not see the text. Let me know if that helps.. :)